# Turbo Table com Checkbox - PrimeNG

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, table

Olá,
Estou utilizando TypeScript, Angular 5, PrimeNG e Java para desenvolvimento de sistema ERP.
Meu front possui uma tela para que o usuário possa escolher os dias de funcionamento do estabelecimento. Esta tela possui um turbo table e uma das colunas é checkbox informando se aquele dia está marcado ou não (aberto ou fechado, na prática). Porém aqui começa o problema...
Fiz a configuração do turbo table conforme especificado na documentação mas todos os checkbox retornam marcados ao carregar os dados ou após algumas alterações que realizei para testes os "checkboxes" não aparecem em um primeiro momento porém caso eu clique na linha ele aparece mas o checkbox só aparece após clicar na sua linha/coluna.
Eu gostaria que, se alguém puder dar uma luz, ao carregar os dados do back-end os "checkboxes" viessem com os valores marcados ou não, a depender do dado carregado. Inclusive caso eu marque ou desmarque um checkbox os valores estão sendo alterados corretamente, porém a sua exibição inicial não está correta... Seguem alguns dados para auxiliar:

HTML - Apenas a table

```
<p-table [value]="dias" [responsive]="true">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-codigo" scope="col">Aberto?</th>
            <th class="col-codigo" scope="col">Código</th>
            <th scope="col">Dia Semana</th>
            <th scope="col">Hora Abertura</th>
            <th scope="col">Hora Fechamento</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-dia>
        <tr>
            <td>
                  <p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="dia.opt_Funcionamento" [value]="dia.opt_Funcionamento"
                    binary="false" name="funcionamento" (onclick)="!dia.opt_Funcionamento"></p-checkbox>
                    </td>
          <td scope="row">
            {{dia.cd_Funcionamento}}
          </td>
          <td scope="row">
            {{dia.dia}}
          </td>
          <td pEditableColumn scope="row">
              <p-cellEditor>
                  <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                      <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="dia.hr_Abertura" [timeOnly]="true" name="horaAbertura" [showSeconds]="true" dataType="string"></p-calendar>
                  </ng-template>
                  <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                      {{dia.hr_Abertura}}
                  </ng-template>
              </p-cellEditor>
          </td>
          <td pEditableColumn scope="row">
              <p-cellEditor>
                  <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                      <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="dia.hr_Fechamento" [timeOnly]="true" name="horaFechamento" [showSeconds]="true" dataType="string"></p-calendar>
                  </ng-template>
                  <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                      {{dia.hr_Fechamento}}
                  </ng-template>
              </p-cellEditor>
          </td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </p-table>
```

Component.ts

```
  export class FuncionamentoEstabelecimentoCadastroComponent {
  @Input () displayValue: string;
  funcionamentoEstabelecimento = new FuncionamentoEstabelecimento();
  dias: FuncionamentoEstabelecimento[];
  aberto = false;
  diaSelecionado: FuncionamentoEstabelecimento;

  constructor(
    ...
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tituloPagina.setTitle('Dias de funcionamento do estabelecimento');
    const codigoFuncionamento = this.rota.snapshot.params['codigo'];
    this.carregaDiasFuncionamento();
}

carregaDiasFuncionamento() {
    this.funcionamentoService.carregaDiasFuncionamento()
      .then(funcionamentoDados => {
        this.dias = funcionamentoDados;
      })
      .catch(erro => this.errorHandler.handle(erro));
  }
```

Model

```
export class FuncionamentoEstabelecimento {
  cd_Funcionamento: number;
  dia: string;
  opt_Funcionamento = false;
  hr_Abertura: Time;
  hr_Fechamento: Time;

}
```

EDIT:
Consegui resolver  o problema. Utilizei o span para a solução. Segue:

```
<td style="text-align: center" scope="row">
                <span *ngIf="rowData.opt_Funcionamento">
                    <p-selectButton [options]="aberto" [(ngModel)]="rowData.opt_Funcionamento"
                      (onOptionClick)="!rowData.opt_Funcionamento" name="diaAberto"
                      pTooltip="Aberto" tooltipPosition="top"></p-selectButton>
                </span>
                <span *ngIf="!rowData.opt_Funcionamento">
                    <p-selectButton [options]="aberto" [(ngModel)]="rowData.opt_Funcionamento"
                    (onOptionClick)="rowData.opt_Funcionamento" name="diaFechado"
                    pTooltip="Fechado" tooltipPosition="top"></p-selectButton>
                </span>
 </td>
```

Comment: Problema resolvido.